# SQL: join tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

With the awesome people's help not too long ago from here, I have this working SQL that receives the first and last names from the full names from a table.

```
select concat(vl.lastname, vf.firstname)
from UserName as t cross apply
 (values (left(t.name, charindex(', ', t.name)), stuff(t.name, 1, 
charindex(', ', t.name) + 1, ''))) vl(lastname, rest) 
cross apply 
(values (left(vl.rest, charindex(' ', vl.rest + ' ')))) vf(firstname)
```

Now I am trying to incorporate this SQL into a join with another table.

```
select t.name, a.LName, a.FName, a.MI
from NewRecruit a
left join UserName t 
on (a.LName + ',' + a.FName) = (t.name =
(
select (vl.lastname + vf.firstname)
from UserName as t cross apply
(values (left(t.name, charindex(', ', t.name)), stuff(t.name, 1, 
charindex(', ', t.name) + 1, ''))) vl(lastname, rest) cross apply
(values (left(vl.rest, charindex(' ', vl.rest + ' ')))) vf(firstname) 
))
```

But I'm getting an error, saying there is incorrect syntax near '='. How can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 1):

You need the correct aliases:

```
. . . (vl.lastname + ',' +  vf.firstName)
```

These columns are not in `NewRecruit`.

Comment: I changed the concat statement to  (vl.lastname + vf.firstname) and I am still seeing the error near '='. Please see my updated SQL in my question.

Comment: @KenshinH . . . You cannot use the variables in an `on` clause  until *after* they are defined in the `values()` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth line has two equal signs.
`on (a.LName + ',' + a.FName) = t.name =`
You need to remove `t.name =`

The sub-query has to return a single row string.

```
select t.name, a.LName, a.FName, a.MI
from NewRecruit a
left join UserName t 
on (a.LName + ',' + a.FName) = (
        select (vl.lastname + vf.firstname)
        from UserName as t cross apply
        (values (left(t.name, charindex(', ', t.name)), stuff(t.name, 1, 
        charindex(', ', t.name) + 1, ''))) vl(lastname, rest) cross apply
        (values (left(vl.rest, charindex(' ', vl.rest + ' ')))) vf(firstname) 
    )
```

You will also fail to find matches here because your first element in the join `(a.LName + ',' + a.FName)` is concatenating the columns and adding a comma, but not a space.